# Cache JSP ByteCode with Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, java, cache, jsp

Is there any way of caching the bytecode for JSP-powered sites with Tomcat? I'm getting *really* fed up of Tomcat taking up all the CPU for 10 minutes while it compiles 4 different webapps every time I restart it.

I'm already using Jikes to "speed up" the compiles, but it's really killing me. The code does not change unless the webapp is upgraded (very rarely), and I cannot believe that there is no way to cache the compiled java bytecode instead of recompiling it each and every time.

I'd appreciate any advice on the matter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

How to precompile JSPs with Tomcat and Ant: 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html